# Why does Maven think I'm referencing slf4j-simple version 1.5.2 when the pom clearly says 1.6.1?

Tags: maven, slf4j

I'm working on a unit test in code that I haven't looked at before.  I noticed that I was getting a NoSuchMethodError with a SLF call.  This apparently is due to different versions of the SLF pieces in the dependency tree.  I see both 1.6.1 and 1.5.2 in various places.  I traced it back to one peer pom that was either referencing version 1.5.2 or none (the 1.5.2 reference was in a plugin dependecy, and the "none" was in the main dependency list).  I changed both references to 1.6.1.  I ran "mvn install" for that module.  I looked at the generated POM in my ~/.m2/repository tree, and it showed both as 1.6.1.  I then ran a "mvn dependency:tree", which the following excerpt is from:

```
[INFO] +- com.somepath.bundle:com.somepath.jira-connector:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.axis:axis:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.axis:axis-jaxrpc:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.axis:axis-saaj:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-discovery:commons-discovery:jar:0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.5.2:compile
```

It's still thinking it's referencing 1.5.2, even after I changed both references in the "jira-connector" pom to 1.6.1.

When I run "mvn test" from the command line, the results are consistent with this, as SLF complains that it found multiple bindings, one of which is the 1.5.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

Use [dependency exclusion mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) to specifically exclude the 1.5.2 version that is coming from jira-connector.

Comment: but, but, WHY is it coming from jira-connector?  I've edited the jira-connector POM and installed it so that the two references to slf4j-simple are 1.6.1, not 1.5.2.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr May be jira connector is coming as a dependency from someother RELEASED artifact that is referencing a RELEASED version of jira connector instead of the SNAPSHOT.

Comment: I just noticed that main artifact version in the jira-connector pom was 1.5.2-SNAPSHOT, but the referencing pom was specifying 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.  Unfortunately, fixing that still doesn't quite fix the problem.  I'll add another response in a moment.

Comment: Now after that fix, I see a similar, but slightly different line in the output:

Comment: Now after that fix, I see a similar, but slightly different line in the output: "[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.5.2:compile (version managed from 1.6.1)".  I don't understand the "version managed from" thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get through this.  I added specific references to both sl4fj-simple and slf4j-api for version 1.6.1 into both projects in question, and now it's ok with it.  This should be defined in a common place, but this will work for these purposes.